# Overriding/excluding ViewResolver for specific ModelAndView route in Controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-boot

Having configured the internal view resolver to:

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}
```

I'm trying to define a specific route in my controller, so it redirects to a JSP that it's not in WEB-INF/jsp/, I'm trying something like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/requiredURL")
public View specificView(){
    return new InternalResourceView("other/package/myView.jsp");
}
```

**But I actually need to pass tome attibutes to the view, so that's why I'm looking for sending a ModelAndView instead.**

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply move it to the JSP directory?

Comment: For requeriments of the project i actually need it outside (There is a filter for authentication purposes, and the outside jsp, needs to be accesible)

Comment: It's actually solved now, maybe I should delete the question.

Comment: I would fix your authorization. But returning a string should work add a `forward:` prefix. `return forward:WEB-INF/index.jsp` forwards the request to the JSP.

Comment: Are you refering to just do `return new ModelAndView("forward:WEB-INF/index.jsp")` without using `InternalResourceView` ? Wouldn't it do the same job?

Comment: No I'm saying return a `String` instead of a `View` or `ModelAndView`. Or even better ditch the controller and configure a view-controller for it.

Comment: The thing is that I need to pass some parameters to the View, that's why I was using a ModelAndView

Comment: That wasn't in your question... Hence the suggestion for a view controller (that is what you get if you don't put actual code or code that represents the actual code).

Comment: It is actually written down the second code example... It wasn't written in code, cause it was my actual doubt, but I will edit the question anyway to make a more clear exmaple, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was posting the question and the answer came to me:

```
@RequestMapping("/your_mapping")
public ModelAndView specificView(){

    InternalResourceView resourceView= new InternalResourceView("other/package/View.jsp");
    Map <> model = new HashMap<>();
    model.put("attubute","atrubute value")
    return new ModelAndView(resourceView,model);
}
```

I just tried it and it works fine. But if anyone has another approach please share.

Thanks.